# Expected identifier before * token

Tags: c++

> Was trying to create a program for calculating the area of triangle using Constructor. ERROR - "error: expected identifier before * token triangle(int b, int h) : *_base(b) , *_height(h) { }"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class triangle {

    const int *_base, *_height;

public: triangle(int b, int h) : *_base(b) , *_height(h) { }

    ~triangle() {
        *_base , *_height;
    }
    double area();
};

double area ( int *_base, int *_height) {

return 0.5 * *_base * *_height;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;

    cin >> a >> b;
    triangle r(a, b);
    cout << r.area();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many things wrong here. Why do you want to use pointers to int instead of just integers?

Comment: The names of the variables are `_height` and `_base`, not `*_height` and `*_base`. And they shouldn’t be pointers.

Comment: It's not terribly clear to me what the destructor is meant to be doing in this code. Even after changing them to the actual variable names instead of `*_base` and `*_height`, it seems to leave them intact.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you wanted to do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class triangle {

    const int _base, _height;

public:
    triangle(int b, int h) : _base(b) , _height(h) { }
    double area();
};

double triangle::area () {
    return 0.5 * (_base) * (_height);
}

int main() {
    int a, b;

    cin >> a >> b;
    triangle r(a, b);
    cout << r.area();

    return 0;
}
```

*_base and *_height are considered as pointers because of the *. Also, I assume that you were trying to define the function area() outside the class. In this case you need to specify the class where it belongs `return_type class::function_name(parameters)`. You don't need to specify the calling object or any attribute of the class in the parameter in the code above as the calling object could be accesses using the `this` pointer. You could also write a friend function if you wish, in that case the function signature in the class would be Case 1: `friend double area(int _base, int _height)` or Case 2: `friend double(triangle tri)` and the function definition outside the class would be:
Case 1:

```cpp
double area(int _base, int _height){
    return 0.5 * _base * _height;
}
```

Case 2:

```cpp
double area(triangle tri){
    return 0.5 * tri._base * tri._height;
}
```

Comment: In your definition of `double triangle::area()` you don't need to write `this->_base` and `this->_height`,  you can just use `_base` and `_height` respectively.